# os.path.expanduser("~") + "/Downloads/" not working

Tags: python, django

In my django app i have specified download location as  `Path = os.path.expanduser("~") + "/Downloads/"`  and it is running in apache2  mod_wsgi server..When i try to download it downloads content inside `/var/www/Downloads`inside a server folder but not users Download directory?What is wrong with my download path?

Comment: I guess the home folder of the user apache run as is `/var/www`. Code you run on the server run as the server not as the client.

Comment: Apache usually runs code as different user, in different folder, with different privileges - all for security reason.

Comment: so any option?iam trying to download content in users local Download directory